# Can't upload image to database Laravel

Tags: laravel, database

I followed a tutorial exactly but the image(path) don't get visible in database. The image is visible in 'storage/app/public/fotos.
I see the table foto in the database but there's always NULL even if I add a photo to database.

```
   // Store Blog
   public function store(Request $request) {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'naam' => 'required',
            'titel' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
            'bericht' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('foto')) {
            $formFields['foto'] = $request->file('foto')->store('fotos', 'public');
        }
```

```
 <form method="POST" action="/home/listings" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
 <div class="mb-6">
                            <label for="foto" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
                                Foto
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type="file"
                                class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full"
                                name="foto"
                            />
                            @error('foto')
                                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{ $message }}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
```

````
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('titel');
            $table->string('foto')->nullable();
            $table->string('tags');
            $table->string('naam');
            $table->longtext('bericht');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('listings');
    }
};
```
````

Comment: where you want to save your photos the path that you used is for saving the photo in public foldet of project and also you create a table and foto is not a STRING it should be BLOB

Answer (score -1):

I don´t know if you need to build your own media manager table, or rule. But there are some lib to laravel that could help you so much. Spatie Media Library
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction